# Slice dataframe between two limits

Tags: pandas

I have this DataFrame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(['14:03','14:03','14:04','14:05','14:06','14:07','14:05','14:06','14:07','14:08'],columns=['hour:min'])
```

I want to slice between two limits, in which the first limits start from the beginning if duplicate and 2nd limit begin from the end if duplicate.
So if the limits are '14:03' and '14:07', then the output should be

```
'14:03','14:03','14:04','14:05','14:06','14:07','14:05','14:06','14:07'
```

Comment: `df['hour:min'].between('14:03', '14:07')`?

Comment: What do you mean by *what i want is to slice between two limits, in which first limits start from beginning if duplicate and 2nd limit start from end if duplicate* ?